# How to get the index of a list of buttons in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a couple of buttons

```
<button id="btn-ok[1]" class="btn-ok"></button>
<button id="btn-failed[1]" class="btn-failed"></button>

<button id="btn-ok[2]" class="btn-ok"></button>
<button id="btn-failed[2]" class="btn-failed"></button>

<button id="btn-ok[3]" class="btn-ok"></button>
<button id="btn-failed[3]" class="btn-failed"></button>
```

And I am running differnt jquery functions for btn-ok and for btn-failed.
I would like to use the index number of the id. How can I obtain it?

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#btn-ok').click(function() {
            console.log('I would like to print the index of the pressed button here. (i.e. 1,2,3)');
        });
  });

</script>
```

Comment: I've never seen css tags defined with [ ] as you did, and this seems wrong on so many levels. You should be instead binding events on class names. Besides that, that seems like an design error, you shouldn't be needing to obtain index etc. Why do you need index anyways?

Comment: I need the index because I need to perform different calls depending the button is pressed. Putting the [ ] was an attempt to deal with the situation. But as I see in the comments it is clearly a bad idea. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use html5's data attributes and separate the index and status into separate elements - I added some teext to each button so it could be easily seen and then the click grabs the data-attributes and console.logs the values.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.btn').click(function() {
     var index = $(this).data('index');
     var status = $(this).data('status')
    
     console.log(index + ' / ' + status);
  }); });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button data-index="1" data-status ="ok" class="btn btn-ok">1 Ok</button>
<button data-index="1" data-status ="failed"  class="btn btn-failed">1 Failed</button>

<button data-index="2" data-status ="ok" class="btn btn-ok">2 OK</button>
<button data-index="2" data-status ="failed" class="btn btn-failed">2 Failed</button>

<button  data-index="3" data-status ="ok" class="btn btn-ok">3 OK</button>
<button  data-index="3" data-status ="failed" class="btn btn-failed">3 Failed</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a collection of all those buttons to index against. Note that [`index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index/) is zero based

```
var $buttons = $('.btn-ok, btn-failed').click(function(){
     alert($buttons.index(this));
})
```

Or for more specifc target:

```
var $buttons = $('.btn-ok, btn-failed');

$('#btn-ok\\[1\\]').click(function(){
     alert($buttons.index(this));
})
```

Or use data attributes instead of messing around with `[]` in ID

```
<button  class="btn-ok" data-index="1"></button>
```

..

```
$('.btn-ok').click(function(){
    alert($(this).data('index'));
})
```

Answer (score 1):

HTML id's shouldn't use an index. Instead use a class to hold the selector and a data attribute to hold the other values you'll need like this:

The HTML:

```
<button class="btn-ok" data-index="1">Ok</button>
```

The JS:

```
$('.btn-ok').click(function() {
   $(this).data('index');
});
```

The fiddle: 
https://jsfiddle.net/kLvqe8dw/2/

Answer (score 0):

did you mean to get id ?

```js
$("button").click(function(){
    alert($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btn-ok[1]" class="btn-ok">ok[1]</button>
<button id="btn-failed[1]" class="btn-failed">failed[1]</button>

<button id="btn-ok[2]" class="btn-ok">ok[2]</button>
<button id="btn-failed[2]" class="btn-failed">failed[2]</button>

<button id="btn-ok[3]" class="btn-ok">ok[3]</button>
<button id="btn-failed[3]" class="btn-failed">failed[3]</button>
```